# Another help, now i wan tot know how can i remove the colliding rect by any other rect?

Tags: python, pygame

**I want to remove the colliding rect by another rect which is not colliding by any one What can i improve in the code given below, basically i want to change the coordinates of the colliding rect within the list **

```
import pygame
from random import randint
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((350,675))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

x_poss = randint(0,350)
y_poss = randint(0,675)
width = 20
height = 20
vel = 8

bases = []

red = (255,0,0)

image_1 = pygame.image.load('bird.png').convert_alpha()
image_2 = pygame.image.load('base.png').convert_alpha()
image_3 = pygame.image.load('base2.png').convert_alpha()
image_4 = pygame.image.load('enemy.png').convert_alpha()

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
run = True

def draw_rect(color, x, y, width, height):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x,y,width, height))

for i in range(5):
    bases.append(pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (randint(0,330), randint(0,675), width, height)))
    bases.append(pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (randint(0,330), randint(0,675), width, height)))


while run:
    pygame.time.delay(50)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key[pygame.K_LEFT] and x_poss > vel - width:
        x_poss -= vel

    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x_poss < 350 - vel - width:
        x_poss += vel

    if not(isJump):
        if key[pygame.K_UP] and y_poss > vel:
            y_poss -= vel

        if key[pygame.K_DOWN] and y_poss < 670 - height - vel:
            y_poss += vel

        if key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            y_poss -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            jumpCount = 10
            isJump = False

    screen.fill((255,255,255))


    for base_1 in bases[:5]:
        screen.blit(image_2, base_1)
    for base_2 in bases[5:]:
        screen.blit(image_3, base_2)

    for i, base in enumerate(bases):
        if base.collidelist(bases[i+1:]) >= 0:
            print('yes')



    draw_rect((0,0,0),300, 440, 10, 10)
    draw_rect((255,255,255),x_poss, y_poss, width, height)

    screen.blit(image_4, pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (300,440,10,10)))
    screen.blit(image_1, pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (x_poss, y_poss, width, height)))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

** What can i improve in the code given below, basically i want to change the coordinates of the colliding rect in the list**

```
for i, base in enumerate(bases):
        if base.collidelist(bases[i+1:]) >= 0:
            print('yes')
```

Comment: Yes the issue had solved. Thanks a lot for the big help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only accept rectangles that do not collide with rectangles that have already been generated when creating the list of rectangles:

```py
# DELETE
# for i in range(5):
#    bases.append(pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (randint(0,330), randint(0,675), width, height)))
#    bases.append(pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (randint(0,330), randint(0,675), width, height)))

bases = []
while len(bases) < 10:
    rect = pygame.Rect(randint(0,330), randint(0,675), width, height)
    if rect.collidelist(bases) < 0:
        bases.append(rect)
```

Note, rectangles can be represented by [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects.

Comment: Hey Rabbid76 can you plz also tell me how  to accept the answers...........plz tell me